# Variable with List comprehension

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm trying to rewrite my old code using list comprehension and I was wondering if there's a way to use a variable called "result" instead of `int(round(sorted_l[sorted_l.index(i)] // sorted_l1[sorted_l1.index(i1)]))`
in the code below, because I will need to reuse it within the function.

```
list1 = [2, 4, 6]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]

def a_function(lst, lst1):
    sorted_l = sorted(lst)
    sorted_l1 = sorted(lst1)
    my_list = [int(round(sorted_l[sorted_l.index(i)] // sorted_l1[sorted_l1.index(i1)])) for i in sorted_l for i1 in sorted_l1]
    most_common = lst.count()
    print my_list
```

Comment: Use a regular `for` loop if you want to keep that result

Comment: Well these `result` values are what go in `list` which you then return, so you have those values available already, right? BTW using `list` as variable name is a terrible idea...

Comment: What is your function meant to `return`?  `count()` takes 1 argument, so this will raise a `TypeError `

Comment: Just a reminder that list comprehensions aren't better just because they are on one line. If a comprehension will require you to write very long and difficult to understand expressions than it's better to use a standard `for` loop. There is no shame in doing things in more than one line. Readability and maintainability trump cleverness every time.

Comment: Is `sorted_l[sorted_l.index(i)]` some kind of joke?

Answer (score 1):

`sorted_l[sorted_l.index(i)]` is the exact same as `i`.

`sorted_l1[sorted_l1.index(i1)]` is the exact same as `i1`.

You are doing integer division, which truncates the decimal, so what are you rounding?

```
int(round( v1 // v2 ))
```

---

That being  said, all that can be simplified to

```
[int(round(i / i1)) for i in sorted_l for i1 in sorted_l1]
```

And outputs

```
[2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 2]
```

> I was wondering if there's a way to use a variable called "result"

Yes, assign that list to a variable named `result`.

If you want to find the "most common" element, you can't use a list-comprehension, but you can do this

```
from collections import Counter
result = [int(round(i / i1)) for i in list1 for i1 in list2]
most_common = Counter(result).most_common()[0][0] # 2 occurs most frequently
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to do, but the function I wrote below behaves equivalent to yours up until the line `most_common = lst.count()` which is invalid, as Chris Rands points out in the comments.

If you clarify what it is you're actually trying to achieve, I can edit this code accordingly.

```
list1 = [2, 4, 6]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]

def a_function(a, b):
    sorted_a = sorted(a)
    sorted_b = sorted(b)

    for element_a in sorted_a:
        for element_b in sorted_b:

            # Can someone smarter than me let me know if
            # anything in this line is redundant?
            yield int(round(element_a)) // element_b


print(list(a_function(list1, list2)))
```

**Output**

```
[2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 2]
```